# What's the error in this argument that Fin$\le_m$Inf

Tags: logic, computability

There must be an error in the following argument since Fin  is not many-one reducible to Inf, I can't seem to find it. Here it is informally (I hope it's straightforward and not confusing):

Take any infinite r.e. set like $K$  and consider the following:

We will enumerate members of $W_{e}$  and $K$  (simultaneously). We start with $A^0=\emptyset$  and at each stage $i$ given $A^i$ if we've found a new element in $K$ then we add it to $A^{i+1}$.  If at this stage we also find a new element in $W_{e}$ then  we let $A^{i+1}=\emptyset$ otherwise let $A^{i+1}=A^i\cup$ whatever new element we found in $K$ (if one was found). If we found a new element of $W_{e}$  at stage $i$, then  we begin enumerating $K$ from scratch at the next stage, otherwise we keep enumerating $K$ where we left off. Regardless of what happens at stage $i$ we keep enumerating $W_{e}$ where we left off in the next stage.

At the end let  $W_{g(e)}=\bigcup_{i<\omega}A^i$

What will then happen is:

1) if $W_{e}$  is finite then at some point no new elements of $W_{e}$  will be found and so we will be able to place all elements of $K$  into $W_{g(e)}$  without $W_{e}$  hindering us. So in the end we will have $W_{g(e)}=K$,  which means $W_{g(e)}$  will be infinite.

2) if $W_{e}$  is infinite, then we will always be finding new elements of $W_{e}$  and we will be put in a loop and never be able keep anything inside of $W_{g(e)}$.  So in the end we will have $W_{g(e)}=\emptyset$,  which means $W_{g(e)}$  will be finite.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When you say that you are trying to make $W_{g(e)}$, you are giving a computable enumeration of a set that should be c.e. in the end. A c.e. enumeration can only put elements into a set, but can not take it out. In your construction, "Each time a new element is found in $W_e$ we clear out everything we have in $W_{g(e)}$" This involves removing elements from your enumeration.

Such a construction of a set which merely has an computable approximation where elements come in and out are not necessarily c.e. sets. There is a general notion of a $n$-c.e. set. These are sets that possess a computable approximation where for each element $x$, it can come in and out of the approximation at most $n$ times. In this sense, the 1-c.e. sets are the ordinary c.e. sets. It is very easy to show that there is a 2-c.e. set that is not c.e.

Comment: I should have specified that $W_{g(e)}$ is really the end result, I should have denoted however much of $K$ I have listed at stage $i$ by $A^i$ ie let $W_{g(e)}=\bigcup_{i<\omega}A^i$ where $A^i$ is the set consisting of however much of $K$ I have been able to list out at stage $i$

Comment: In another way of seeing the error is that there is no function $g$ with the desired property. In these $m$-reduction question, you always need to use the s-m-n (or sometimes called the parameter theorem) to get the $g$. Don't skip this step. To apply this you a need a partial computable of two variable $\Psi(e,x)$ such that $\Psi(e,x) \downarrow$ if and only if $x$ really does end up in what you called $W_{g(e)}$. You will not be able to come up with this $\Psi$ which is partial computable.